# Why does my JQuery script seems to only works before beginning to browse my tabs if the content of my tabs is the same everywhere?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Why does the JQuery script I use in all my pages seems to only works before beginning to browse my tabs if the content of my tabs is the same everywhere ?

I have a tab view web page built with JQuery and AJAX.

This is my JQuery functions:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box .more").click(function(event){
        alert('test'); 
    });

    $("a.linkTab").click(function(event){
        var tabID = $('.linkTab')[0].toString().split('#')[1];
        $.ajax({
            url : "loadPage.php?tabID=" + tabID,
            success : function (data) {
                $('#body').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is my body web page:

```
<div id="header">...</div>
<div id="body">
    <div class="box">
        <p class="more">LinkLike</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer"><a href="#9">9</a></div>
```

loadPage.php only include needed page that Ajax script sent.

My tab system works perfectly, I can navigate in the page I want. Before navigating, When I click on the LinkLike, the alert appears. But, when I browse tabs, When I click, there is nothing.

Why does the JQuery script seems to only works before beginning to browse.

Important, the file I imports from php contains exactly the same body than the first one. The file contains:

```
<div class="box">
    <p class="more">LinkLike</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$(document).delegate(".box .more","click",function(event){
        alert('test'); 
    });
```

the reason probably is you can generating the link dynamically, and event handlers do not attach themselves to the dynamically inserted elements to the DOM. Previously `.live` was used but that now is deprecated, if you are using jquery version 1.7+ you can use the `.on` method or else you can use the `delegate` method to attach the event handler to the dynamic content. However you can also re-bind the events in the success callback of ajax request

```
$.ajax({
            url : "loadPage.php?tabID=" + tabID,
            success : function (data) {
                $('#body').html(data);
                $(".box").bind("click");
            }
        });
```

[**jQuery.on**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) *version1.7+*

[**jQuery.delegate**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing the entire body of the page when your click event fires; therefore, you will need to re-bind your click events once the new content is loaded.

$(document).ready blocks will only fire when the initial document loads, so the AJAX-ed in content will not cause the click events to be bound again, you'll have to do this in the success callback of the click event that replaces the body content.

```
function init() {
  $("a.linkTab").click(function(event){
    var tabID = $('.linkTab')[0].toString().split('#')[1];
    $.ajax({
        url : "loadPage.php?tabID=" + tabID,
        success : function (data) {
            $('#body').html(data);
            init(); // re-bind events again

        }
    });
  });
}
```

NOTE:  This method will work, but it's probably a bit naive.  Check out this jQuery page for more details on how to use the ["delegate" jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).  The delegate method will bind click events both now as well as in the future.

Here is an example using "on", which supersedes "delegate" as of jQuery 1.7+:

```
// I'm not sure if you're referring to "body" the body tag or "body" the id of your div.      
  // Please adjust accordingly.
$("body").on("click", "a.linkTab", function() {
    var tabID = $('.linkTab')[0].toString().split('#')[1];
    $.ajax({
        url : "loadPage.php?tabID=" + tabID,
        success : function (data) {
            $('#body').html(data);
          }
    });
});
```

Comment: $('#body') does not point to the <div id="body"></div> ? It's point to the page obdy ?

Comment: I mentioned in the comment to adjust accordingly depending on whether you're only wanting to bind future events on the DIV or the actual BODY element.  #body means "tag with the id="body" whereas "body" means page body.  I generally avoid using the id="body" because of the confusion it can create.  I suggest "content" or "wrapper" or something clearly distinct. :)